# How queue scriptaculous and non-scriptaculous effects/events

Tags: css, scriptaculous

I have an series of effects/events that work onclick (to give the effect of minimizing a window) - in overview as follows:

- change css_style.overflow to "hidden"
- scriptaculous - effect to reduce the scale of the div
- scriptaculous - effect to move the div (to corner of screen).

These work fine, but when I try to reverse the process (to give the effect of maximizing/restoring the window - I need to delay the 'overflow:visible' until the scriptaculous effects have finished.
Scriptaculous documentation refers to an 'afterFinish' parameter, but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone assist please.  Or is there a better solution?
The code I want to run AFTER the other effects have finished is:
    getElementById("divId").style.overflow="visible";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `afterFinish` callback you can use. For example:

```
   new Effect._____('myElement', { duration: 1, afterFinish: function() { 
        ... your code ... 
      } 
   });
```

Comment: I think? that's what I'm trying, but it takes effect in parallel. The code I'm using is:

Comment: <script> function x1() { $('div1').morph('width:480px;height:70px;position:absolute;'); new Effect.Move('div1',{ x:-196,y:-360,mode:'relative'}); $('div1_a').appear({duration:3.0}); $('Div1Minimised').fade({duration:0.25 ,afterFinish:FP_changeProp(/*id*/'div1',0,'style.overflow','visible') }); // FP_changeProp(/*id*/'div1',0,'style.overflow','visible'); return false; } </script>       @Diodeus

Comment: Thanks - by putting in VERY large durations I see that it IS indeed working, I now just need to sort out how long each effect should take ... and ensure that afterFinish is on the longest.   Thanks VERY much for you help.

Comment: The issue is you need to wrap the afterFinish in an anonymous function that has your function inside it (see my example). That is why it is happening in parallel, rather than afterward.

Comment: Example: afterFinish:FP_changeProp(/*id*/'div1',0,'style.overflow','visible') becomes: afterFinish:function() {FP_changeProp(/*id*/'div1',0,'style.overflow','visible')}

Comment: Ah!!  I had done that (from your example) ... but didn't realise (till now) that it was that which got it working - thanks again.

Comment: Worth reading: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/